# Coloured Text on Background Shape not Showing - Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, text-wrap

Many thanks if you can help stop me banging my head against this brick wall.

Part of the text in a text box I would like coloured against a shape background. Instead of acting as expected, it "disappears" - text is actually selectable, but doesn't show.

No text-wrapping is applied, and it isn't overset. I want the text white, but I've colored it blue to ensure there is no white text issue.

Text is at the top of the layer stack.

It isn't either of the solutions here:

https://creativepro.com/where-is-my-text/
https://creativepro.com/the-curious-case-of-occasional-overset/

Text I want to show against the background in blue:

[image: Text I want to show against the background in blue]

How it appears when background added:

[image: How it appears when background added]

Thanks if you can help at all.

Kind regards

Comment: Is the text set to overprint?

Comment: No, No overprint set in Edit > preferences > Appearance of Black

Comment: What blend mode does the text frame have?

Comment: Not in the preferences.. if you select the text and look at the attributes panel.. is it set to overprint?